# Is it possible to `git add` a list of files from a file?

Tags: git

Suppose I have a list of files (newline delimited) in a file, and I want to `git add` all these files.

Is there some way to do this directly?

I have checked online and looked at `git help add`, but did not see anything that helps.

Comment: @BrianRoach, I agree it is a more specific case of the other question, but when I was trying to solve this problem, the first thing that comes to mind is not to Google for "command line arguments from a file content". Therefore I think this question will still be beneficial for future seekers.

Comment: Do this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4227994/how-do-i-use-the-lines-of-a-file-as-arguments-of-a-command/4229346#4229346. But, replace `some_command $line` with `git add $line`.

Comment: Cancel that; use this answer instead! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4227994/how-do-i-use-the-lines-of-a-file-as-arguments-of-a-command/60276836#60276836

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use xargs:

```
xargs -a file -d '\n' git add
```

Comment: doesn't work for me because it takes my file content as one string. I use https://stackoverflow.com/a/4228046/6614155 … ```git add `cat my-file-list` ``` my-file-list contains list on only one line.