# How to assign variables from the file in a loop

Tags: bash, file, variables

I'm trying to write a bash script that will read pairs of variables from the file and then uses them in a loop. i'm trying to use this

```
while read p; do $p; echo "$a and $b"; done < text.txt
```

with the text.txt containing the following:

```
a="teststring"; b="anothertest"
a="teststring1"; b="anothertest1"
a="teststring2"; b="anothertest2"
```

the output looks like that:

```
bash: a="teststring";: command not found
 and
bash: a="teststring1";: command not found
 and
```

I have found similar question [command line arguments from a file content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4227994/command-line-arguments-from-a-file-content)

But couldn't figure out how to apply the answers to my particular case. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29108949/awk-parse-out-key-value-pairs-into-variables

Answer (score 0):

One solution using the evil `eval`, just for tests purpose, not to use in production :

```
while read line; do
    eval "$line"
    echo "$a and $b"
done < file.txt
```

### Output:

```
teststring and anothertest
teststring1 and anothertest1
teststring2 and anothertest2
```

### Please read

http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/eval

Comment: Beat me, including warning for `eval`! Personal use is fine, for scripting stuff, but no production.