# How do I read BASH parameters correctly from a file?

Tags: bash

I have this configuration file in my CI where I'm specifying a header file and some CMAKE flags on one line.

The configuration file looks like this (`filelist`):

```
./settings6.h -DMY_COMPILE_FLAGS="-m32 -fstrict-aliasing"
./settings7.h -DMY_FEATURE_1=ON
./settings8.h -DMY_FLAG=ON -DMY_FEATURE_2=ON -DMY_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/include/
```

Now, I'm using a bash script to process this configuration file:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
SCRIPTDIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"
while read i; do
    HEADERFILE=$(echo $i | cut -d ' ' -f 1)
    CMAKEFLAGS=$(echo $i | cut -s -d ' ' -f 2-)
    if [[ "$HEADERFILE" == "" ]]; then
        continue
    fi
    CFLAGS="-Werror" cmake "my_build_dir" "$CMAKEFLAGS" -G "Ninja" -DMY_EXTRA_INCLUDE="$SCRIPTDIR/$HEADERFILE" -B"build_env_dir" > /dev/null
    ninja -C "build_env_dir"
done <<ENDOFINPUT
$(grep -v '^#' $SCRIPTDIR/filelist)
ENDOFINPUT
```

When I have the bash script as above, the line with `settings6.h` gets processed properly, i.e. the `MY_COMPILE_FLAGS` are set to `-m32 -fstrict-aliasing`.

However, `settings8.h` is failing because the value of `MY_FLAG` is seen by CMAKE as `ON -DMY_FEATURE_2=ON -DMY_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/include/`, so `MY_FEATURE_2` and `MY_INCLUDE_DIR` are not processed correctly.

After googling around a bit, I thought, well, surely a quoting issue, probably I have to remove the quotes around `$CMAKEFLAGS` like this:

```sh
    CFLAGS="-Werror" cmake "my_build_dir" $CMAKEFLAGS -G "Ninja" -DMY_EXTRA_INCLUDE="$SCRIPTDIR/$HEADERFILE" -B"build_env_dir" > /dev/null
```

In fact, this lets `settings8.h` work as expected (all three options are processed), but now, `settings6.h` is suddenly failing since CMAKE complains:

```
CMake Error: The source directory "/src/-fstrict-aliasing"" does not exist
```

Can someone guide me please how I read the settings correctly from my `filelist` so that `settings6.h` and `settings8.h` both succeed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12136948/why-does-shell-ignore-quotes-in-arguments-passed-to-it-through-variables

Comment: @tripleee I actually don't think this is a duplicate: passing `$CMAKEFLAGS` as array doesn't improve anything. Do you have another suggestion?

Comment: The best proposal I can come up with is to modify your input file format so that you *can* parse it without `eval` or other horrible workarounds. Wrapping this in a Makefile comes to mind as one potentially rather elegant workaround.

Comment: @tripleee do you have an example (maybe you post it as an answer) how such a file format would look like?

Comment: If you are using `cmake` anyway I would probably use that for the whole thing, but I'm not familiar enough with it to show you how.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4227994/how-do-i-use-the-lines-of-a-file-as-arguments-of-a-command

Comment: @tripleee I finally went for doing it all with CMAKE. Thanks for poining me there!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a `Makefile` which refactors this into a sequence of recipes.

```
Cases := $(patsubst %.h,%,$(wildcard ./settings*.h))
all_done := $(patsubst %,.%.done,$(Cases))

.PHONY: all
all: $(all_done)

cases.mk: filelist.txt
    sed 's%^\./%case_%;s% % := %' $< >$@
include cases.mk

.%_done: ./%.h
    CFLAGS="-Werror" cmake "my_build_dir" $(case_$*) -G "Ninja" \
        -DMY_EXTRA_INCLUDE="$<" -B"build_env_dir" > /dev/null
    ninja -C "build_env_dir"
```

Comment: Not in a place where I can test this but hopefully this can at least inspire some lateral thinking...