# Adding 6 directories in single line command in txt file using shell

Tags: linux, git, shell

Facing the below error -

```
fatal: ambiguous argument '`SS_FrameProtoco SS_Codec SS_WcdmaEngineDrivers SS_LocalOam SS_LocalTelecom SS_W1plT`':
```

> unknown revision or path not in the working tree. Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this: 'git  [...] -- [...]'

How to solve this error?  I wanted to add two different digits in one single line.

> ```
> git log --shortstat --since "01.06.2020" --until "1.12.2020" \
> SS_FrameProtocol SS_Codec SS_WcdmaEngineDrivers SS_LocalOam \
> SS_LocalTelecom SS_W1plTx   | grep "files changed" | awk '{files+=$1;
> inserted+=$4; deleted+=$6} END {print "files changed", files, "lines
> inserted:", inserted, "lines deleted:", deleted}'
> ```

This command is working but I want to pass the directory name(s) in a text file.

Comment: You can specify the directory names using `$(cat text.file)` in place of the directory names.  You should prefix that with `--`, as the error message suggests.

Answer (score 0):

In case your folders might have space in them (not the case in your question, but that could happen), you could follow the [approach described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22517974/6309):

```sh
declare -a args=()
while IFS='' read -r -d '' item; do
  args+=( "$item" )
done <file
git log --shortstat --since "01.06.2020" --until "1.12.2020" -- "${args[@]}" | ...
                                                            ^^^^
```

As noted, don't forget the double-hyphen `--` (I [mentioned that syntax here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1192194/6309))